# AutoLayout with Masnory get warning

Tags: ios, autolayout

I add a button at top and a label below button in tableviewcell use autolayout with masnory, everything is work well but i get some message something like warning.

Row height calculate

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.mycell == nil) {
        self.mycell = [[AutoLayoutTableViewCell alloc] init];
    }
    self.mycell.label.text = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.mycell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self.mycell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    self.mycell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.mycell.bounds));
    [self.mycell setNeedsLayout];
    [self.mycell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGFloat height = [self.mycell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    height += 1;
    return height;
}
```

Here is my constraints

```
    UIView *root = self.contentView;

    [self.btn mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.height.mas_equalTo(80);
        make.top.equalTo(root).offset(16);
        make.leading.top.equalTo(root).offset(16);
        make.trailing.equalTo(root).offset(-16);
    }];

    [self.label mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.btn.mas_bottom).offset(10);
        make.leading.equalTo(root).offset(16);
        make.trailing.equalTo(root).offset(-16);
        make.bottom.equalTo(root).offset(-16);
    }];
```

And get warning message.

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: 
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdce2437210 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdce242a900.height == 44>",
"<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fdce243aa40 UIButton:0x7fdce2434620.height == 80>",
"<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fdce243b080 UIButton:0x7fdce2434620.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdce242a900.top + 16>",
"<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fdce243bcc0 UILabel:0x7fdce2427cc0.top == UIButton:0x7fdce2434620.bottom + 10>",
"<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fdce243c550 UILabel:0x7fdce2427cc0.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdce242a900.bottom - 16>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fdce243aa40 UIButton:0x7fdce2434620.height == 80>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cell is 44 pt tall (see the first constraint in the error message), but you’re pinning the label and button vertically together inside the cell, and their combined height is taller than 44 pt. You probably want your cell to be taller. You can accomplish this by setting `rowHeight` on your `UITableView`, or use [iOS 8’s self-sizing cells](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/):

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Are you sure your method is returning the right thing? Because the cell content view definitely has a “height == 44” constraint on it.

Comment: As for sizing the cells yourself, you may want to look at how [RZCellSizeManager](https://github.com/Raizlabs/RZCellSizeManager) does it. It’s slightly different than what you are doing.

Comment: Try setting a symbolic breakpoint for `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`. When is the error occurring? During your `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`? Or when the table view is laying out?